# JOIN on a table where a field not equal to a value

Tags: mysql, join, left-join

I have this query:

```
SELECT `A`.*, `LNK`.`act_id`, `LNK`.`remaining`, `U`.`username` as U_username
FROM (`anagrafiche` as A)
LEFT JOIN `lnk_ana-act` AS LNK ON `A`.`id` = `LNK`.`ana_id`
LEFT JOIN `users` AS U ON `A`.`uid` = `U`.`id`
WHERE (`LNK`.`act_id` != 57 OR `LNK`.`act_id` IS NULL) AND A.closed = '0'
LIMIT 10
```

This query selects ALL fields where act_id is not 57, resulting on several duplicates of the first table "anagrafiche". It's obviously wrong to do it like this, what should I do in this case?

Thanks

EDIT CLARIFICATION.

I want only one record of the first table regardless of how many lnk_ana-act records there are. To be more precise there are thousands of records lnk_ana-act table that are not equal to `act_id` != 57, but I only need one unique record of the "anagrafiche" table regardless of how many records in the joined table

Comment: What's your expected result? Which records do you want to obtain?

Comment: is this a requirement to use LEFT Join ? I mean do u need rows from first table even if their matching rows are not found in second table ?

Comment: @Marco I want only one record of the first table regardless of how many lnk_ana-act records there are.

Comment: @Zohaib yes I need the LEFT join for the reason you wrote.

Comment: @0plus1 Its a bit confusing, You need only one unique record from the first table, and you are also using LEFT join. Are there duplicate records in first table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand what you need. try this:

```
SELECT A.*, LNK.act_id, LNK.remaining, U.username as U_username
FROM anagrafiche A LEFT JOIN lnk_ana-act LNK 
    ON A.id = LNK.ana_id
LEFT JOIN users U 
    ON A.uid = U.id
WHERE LNK.act_id <> 57 AND A.closed = '0'
GROUP BY A.id
LIMIT 10
```